# My efforts were wasted

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, moderation

This morning, I wasted about 2 hours of my time installing Anaconda on Windows.

Long story short: The Anaconda installer failed to add a path variable.

---

I discovered that there were approximately 20 open questions pertaining to this very same issue. Approximately 3 of the 20 included the solution that I used to solve my problem.

So I intended to paste my answer to the remaining 17 questions, link those questions to the questions which already included the same answer, and then vote-to-close all 17.

**EDIT** Why did I copy and paste my answer? Because my close vote does not guarantee that the question will be closed!

Unfortunately, @martijn-pieters took a very dogmatic approach, and instead of following my lead and voting to close all of the duplicates, he simply deleted my copied and pasted answer (which I will acknowledge is the typical moderator response when an SO user simply copies and pastes and answer).

---

Bottom Line:

1. I don't have a huge problem with @martijn-pieters' decision to delete my duplicate answers.
2. But why didn't he vote to close the duplicates as well? Now, other people will hit the duplicates, miss my answer, and waste their time as well.

Comment: [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/310998)

Comment: You should have just posted one canonical answer and just vote to close the others **without posting duplicate answers!** (I could only guess that the mod either isn't an expert in that topic or he just responded to an auto-flag which showed that you posted the exact same answer 17 times and he deleted them)

Comment: @Rizier123: No! I just added an explanation for that. My vote-to-close does not guarantee closure! In light of this fact, many people will waste hours of their time as well.

Comment: As for "why didn't he vote to close the duplicates as well": moderators are not experts on every topic on Stack Overflow and they might not have the knowledge required to decide whether a question should be closed as a duplicate of another question. Also, they may just not have enough time to look at all these 17 questions to check if they're duplicates.

Comment: @JimG. Copy-pasting answers is far from being helpful. Being helpful is having a centralized Q&A with all of the information in it, that can later be updated to keep with the changes occuring in various frameworks.

Comment: @JimG. I couldn't agree more, we need to think differently. But I'll maintain that copy-pasting answers is not the way to go. Cast your close votes and see what happens. C++ and Qt gold badge holders may filter the CV queue with those tags and see them. Check back in a few days, and if you see no progress, and you're convinced they're dupes, ask for help in a chatroom.

Comment: @duplode that is true but I do agree with attempts to actually close proper dupes as that is a better service for future visitors and increases the chance to find the best answer.

Comment: I note that the only two answers you haven't had deleted (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40329342/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/a/40329298/3001761) **also do this**. Please use dupe VTCs rather than spamming identical answers.

Answer (score 34):

> I just added an explanation for that. My vote-to-close does not guarantee closure!

So what?

You do not have sole responsibility for fixing everything that is wrong on SO. By providing a canonical answer and voting to close the rest as a duplicate, you've done all you can and *should* do.

I appreciate the impulse to help. But you cannot fix everything on this site by yourself. And no *one person* should be able to. If you see something wrong here that you alone cannot fix, then do what you can (answer and VTC), then bring it up on MSO.

> But why didn't he vote to close the duplicates as well?

Because that's not what moderators do. Or at least, not in that way. The mod in question probably saw an automatic flag from the system about someone duplicating their answers. So they went and removed the answers. In all likelihood, no detailed investigation was launched or anything. Just linking directly to the answers and pressing "delete".

Comment: Flagging to close as duplicate is completely wrong thing to do... Consider editing that part out or even add "don't flag for moderator attention when you can perform action yourself".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've gone ahead and removed that paragraph. Indeed, people should NOT flag posts for moderator attention to ask them to close the posts.