# Failing Meta Review Queue Question

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I regularly review posts in the Meta SO Review queue. Today, I went to refresh the page and this appeared:

[image]

Here's the question link:

[My efforts were wasted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337145/my-efforts-were-wasted)

Taking a look at how other reviewers voted:

[image]

Seems I'm not the only one that voted to close it - but I've been penalised for thinking like the majority of voters.

If someone could please explain what has happened here, that would be great because I'm a little confused!

Answer (score 6):

You voted to close a question as a duplicate when it was *completely* different from the proposed duplicate, and was in no way answered by that duplicate.  You were apparently not paying close enough attention when reviewing posts, and have been given some time off of the queues as a result.  That you weren't the only one to make this mistake in no way changes the fact that you made an egregious mistake, nor does it absolve you of the consequences.

Comment: That's fine, as a past reviewer of regular posts on SO I am aware there are levels and limits to the timeout periods. To my knowledge, I have never hit this on MSO - so to be hit with a 7 day timeout seems excessive by comparison!

Comment: @Luke manual bans (on any site, not just meta) aren't subject to standard timeouts.  When a moderator manually bans you from reviewing, they can select a timeout.  We can only guess why the mod selected 7 days, but given the duplicate had no bearing on the question, it is likely the mod felt it was serious enough to skip the shorter ban

Comment: @Luke I'm not sure if you have seen [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336622/can-we-talk-about-the-reviewing-culture-here-on-meta) but that might have contributed to the moderators taking a closer look at Meta CVQ reviews.

Comment: @rene More likely someone just flagged that post.

Comment: @rene I had no idea, thanks. A shame reading some of the comments/posts there, sounds like a witch-hunt. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Luke yep, but that matches Halloween nicely ...

Comment: @Luke  A witch hunt is when people are persecuted for having done nothing wrong.  When people are facing deserved consequences for actually having demonstrably done something wrong that merits those consequences, it ceases to be a witch hunt.